# Azure Service Bus - Scheduled Messages Filtering

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Is there a way to apply filtering/querying on the scheduled messages placed on the topic? I'm aware that I can read through all the scheduled messages from the topic and apply in-memory filtering but if there are a million messages that are placed inside the topic then this leads to memory and compute intense operations.

Is there a way to query only the specific scheduled messages and delete them from the topic?

I was thinking of using topic subscriptions to do the filtering, but to my knowledge, the messages are available to the subscription only when the schedule is expired

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

If you’d like the feature, here’s a tracking [feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/95).